# HttpError 503, while creating subnet using GCP Python API

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-apis-explorer

Hello Everyone,
              Need your thoughts on an issue I am getting with a python script to create vpc and subnet.

My script is working fine when creating vpc, but next step of subnet creation is failing with error

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 503 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<projectname>/regions/us-east1/subnetworks?alt=json returned "Internal error. Please try again or contact Google Support.
```

I am able to create subnet from UI and from rest API page.

Here is the script code I am using for subnet creation-

````
def create_subnet(compute, project, region, classname):

    subnetname = classname
    networkpath = 'projects/<projectname>/global/networks/%s' % (classname)
    ipCidrRange = "10.0.0.0/16"

    config = {
  "name": subnetname,
  "network": networkpath,
  "ipCidrRange": ipCidrRange
}

    print('##### Print Config ##### %s' % (config))

    return compute.subnetworks().insert(
        project=project,
        region=region,
        body=config).execute()
    ```
````

def main(project, classname, zone, region):

````
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')

print('Creating vpc')

operation = create_vpc(compute, project, classname)

print('Creating subnet')

operation = create_subnet(compute, project, region, classname)
```
````

Thanks in advance for comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the root cause of this issue. I was making subnet call without waiting for vpc create operation to complete.

Created new function to wait and call it after vpc creation step resolves the issue.

```
def wait_for_global_operation(compute, project, operation):
    print('Waiting for operation to finish...')
    while True:
        result = compute.globalOperations().get(
            project=project,
            operation=operation).execute()

        if result['status'] == 'DONE':
            print("done.")
            if 'error' in result:
                raise Exception(result['error'])
            return result

        time.sleep(1)
```

Thanks Lozano for your comments and feedback.

Comment: Nice work @Dev, Thanks for share, overcome the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the a wrong label syntax. Try the following syntax for network and region:

> "network":
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXX/global/networks/XXXXX",
>   "region":
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXX/regions/XXXXX"

The online API Explorer can be pretty helpful[1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/list?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22wave17-jlozano%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22us-west1%22%7D).

---

Comment: Thanks, Lozano for your answer. I am using API Explorer, and check all parameters from API explorer, which seems fine.

If I try to use region in format 'projects/XXXXX/regions/XXXXX', I got error


```
Invalid value 'projects/XXXXX/regions/XXXXX'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?'">
```

Comment: I supose you changed the XXXX according to your own particular project and region. I tested it out with my project and its working perfectly, I don't even need the region variable, only ipCidrRange, network and name.

Comment: That's right, Lozano. I replace XXXX with the required inputs. I am not sure how it works without region variable.

Region is mandatory parameter for Method: subnetworks.insert.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/insert?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22presalesdemo%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22us-east1%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22testvpc%22%2C%22network%22%3A%22projects%2Fpresalesdemo%2Fglobal%2Fnetworks%2Ftestvpc%22%2C%22ipCidrRange%22%3A%2210.0.0.0%2F16%22%7D%7D